What is the machine that the beer taps are attached to called?
A beer dispenser? A beer dispensing system?


Where did you get the photo? Did it have a caption? Who is the manufacturer? Is it a home thing or for some other special purpose? That doesn't look the sort of system that's usual in Europe or North America, at least not in bars, etc. But beer dispenser sounds fine.

It looks like it is a chiller for lager (in UK beer is not chilled in the same way, but the kegs/barrels are kept in a cool room or cellar, at not such a low temperature as lager needs to be).

That picture is from a site in French: tireuse à bière professionnelle et portative: professional, portable beer dispenser

That machine is attached to beer kegs through tubes.

The crucial point is that it may chill the beer/lager. Otherwise there is no need for that cabinet.

I'm no barman, but I'd have thought the crucial point might be that it pressurizes the beer. Whatever - it seems they're called Beer Dispensers, as @Lambie has already noted

...I never actually looked at the contents of my link, beyond a couple of seconds to see they had pictures similar to OP's. But a few more seconds looking at the text itself gives me the strong impression pressure is way more important than temperature from the manufacturers' perspective.

Can you please tell me what it is called?

Beer taps, also known as draft beer towers or draft arms, are mounted on top of a counter or kegerator. The tap tower holds the beer lines and beer faucets in place. The number of faucets on a tap tower determines how many different beers can be served at the same time.

Thank you but what's the machine in the picture called?

"The number of faucets on a tap tower determines how many different beers can be served at the same time." This was not part of the question and seems like AI-generated content.
